# Talend Environment Setup?

Tags: talend

I'm a new bee to Talend and I want understand Talend enterprise more from a system setup in all the environments. The scenario is -

Given      - Talend Enterprise edition

Systems  - Dev, Test, Production

Confusion -

1. If the Talend server server is installed in Dev then, do i need to install the same setup in Test or Production? The concern raised is because -

In deployment using TAC, I'll just move my artifacts to the Nexus repository and thereafter it'll deployed to the target job server (where the job will execute). In that case do I need to install Talend Server for the other two?

2. If no, then what sort of components do I need to install in Test and Production? What should be the ideal environment setup for a customer environments?
3. Will there be only one TAC for all the environments?

Can someone please shed some light on the above concerns.

Thanks in anticipation -

Santosh G

Answer (score 0):

Got the answers -

1. The confusion was created by the Server parameter in the TAC. I thought it was the target server like (Test or Prod) where the job would be deployed. Instead, it was the job/execution server. So, will have to install the Talend setup in all environments.
2. Doesn't come in picture.
3. Every environment where Talend server is installed will have a separate TAC.

Thanks,
Santosh G.